# Jquery UI sortable, button is not working as handle

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, handle, jquery-ui-sortable

I am trying to sort `tr's` in a table.

**code**

```
$("table tbody").sortable({
    handle: 'button'
    //handle: 'img'
}).disableSelection();
```

[live fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uttara/22C2n/701/)

now the problem is when using `img` as handle its working fine

but when using `button` as handle its not working

I checked for many jquery ui sortable ques for my ans but of no help

can anyone plz explain why is this happening

Thanx in advance

Comment: Simplified jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r02vwvd1/1/

Answer (score 75, accepted):

The `cancel` option defaults to `:input,button` which conflicts with your handle setting.  Just setting it to an empty string works fine.

```
$("table tbody").sortable({ 
    handle: 'button',
    cancel: ''
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/22C2n/705/

Comment: thanx a lot Nal :) How I overlooked the default option for cancel!!

Comment: $("table tbody").sortable({
    handle: 'button',
    cancel: ''
}).disableSelection();

Comment: `handle` option has replaced with `items`
[option-handle](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-handle)
[option-items](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-items)